# Is it possible to record from the external mic when recording video in Android?

Tags: android, video, audio, record

I've been asking around in developer circles about this, but so far no one has been able to confirm if it is possible. The default behavior for recording video in Android is to not use the external mic. I'd like to create an app that uses an external mic if it is available, but it seems like this might be tricky for some reason. Anyone have insight into this?

It seems like it would just be a matter of selecting it at this point in the recording setup:

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
```

but it seems like there may be some oddness in doing that.

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior in Android 12 (and I understand starting at 8 or 9) is that external microphones become the primary and default source for input.

It probably depends on the app, but at least video in the default camera app takes my external mic as default.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) (look in the section titled "Performing Audio Capture") it covers setting up the audio capture.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seems like it should be possible, given that voice recording is able to successfully use the external mic. However, I wonder if there is some bug in the implementation for video recording, seeing that it defaults to the internal mic typically.

Comment: I've never tried recording video and audio so i'm not sure if there are any bugs, have you tried using CAMCORDER or MIC as the audio source rather than DEFAULT?