# How to use external mic on Android?

Tags: android, audio-recording, microphone

How to use external mic instead of the phone's mic for recording?

I found that the Google default Camera app uses phone's mic no matter what, but some Apps from Play Store can use external mic. So there must be a way to do that.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948769/

Answer (score 3):

In your code, when you do:

```
AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord.Builder()
.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION) ...
```

Use the appropriate [MediaRecorder.AudioSource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html), which would be [MIC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#MIC)